# InterstitialAd show first and move onto next activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, interstitial

I am using Kotlin and android studio trying to implement interstitial ad and banner ad. Banner ad works perfectly. As for the interstitial ad, even though it is set up perfectly, (testing ad shows fine) but the problem is that interstitial is loaded same time with the next activity that technically, interstitial ad is running behind my second activity. I am just afraid that this might cause violation.

Sorry for my poor english but what I want to do is when i click start, interstitial ad pops up and the second activity only shows after the ad is closed...

```
 private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this@MainActivity)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)

    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())


    btn_start.setOnClickListener {

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        }
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Allquiz::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
    }
}
```

}

Please kindly help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous because ad and activity are opening same time.

```
  if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
      mInterstitialAd.show()
  }
  val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Allquiz::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
  finish()
```

There are two ways of achieving this.

The first way is to listen ad  [events](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#ad_events). After ad closed then the activity can be opened

```
override fun onAdClosed() {
   // The ad is closed. Go to other activity here 
}
```

Second way is to open activity first, then showing ad

For me, the second way simple. So you don't have to deal with other ad events